# Convert SQL Server T-SQL to SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have been trying out a code using `pivot`  to get a certain view from a table .

```
create table temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table temp
```

I get an error in the `declare` statement and also `pivot` is not being recognised as a keyword by dbviz SQL commander

I even removed the `@` and tried to run it , I'm not able to execute successfuly

I'm using Oracle Database 11g ( oracle JDBC driver )

Comment: this is definitely not an oracle syntax. Can you show us your effort on converting this tsql to plsql?

Comment: And which version of Oracle are you using ?

Comment: Instead of trying to convert your T-SQL code to Oracle code, it would be much easier if you showed output that you are expecting given a set of sample data.

Comment: I'm using Oracle db , but we write queries using SQL. `pivot` is not treated as a keyword. I  cannot understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to run this code from SQLPlus or SQLcl, you can use code below to generate the same information in Oracle.

#### Oracle 19c and later

In Oracle 19, Oracle introduce the ability to do `LISTAGG(DISTINCT <value>)` which removes the need to do a subquery to remove any duplicates.

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
    date_val    DATE,
    category    VARCHAR (3),
    amount      NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-01-01', 'ABC', 1000.00);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-02-01', 'DEF', 500.00);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-02-01', 'GHI', 800.00);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-02-10', 'DEF', 700.00);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-03-01', 'ABC', 1100.00);

column category_list NEW_VALUE categories

SELECT '''' || LISTAGG (DISTINCT category, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category) || ''''    AS category_list
  FROM temp;

SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT date_val, amount, category FROM temp) x
       PIVOT (MAX (amount) FOR category IN (&categories)) p;

DROP TABLE temp;
```

#### Earlier than Oracle 19c

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
    date_val    DATE,
    category    VARCHAR (3),
    amount      NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-01-01', 'ABC', 1000.00);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-02-01', 'DEF', 500.00);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-02-01', 'GHI', 800.00);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-02-10', 'DEF', 700.00);

INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (DATE '2012-03-01', 'ABC', 1100.00);

column category_list NEW_VALUE categories

SELECT '''' || LISTAGG (category, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category) || ''''    AS category_list
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category
          FROM temp);

SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT date_val, amount, category FROM temp) x
       PIVOT (MAX (amount) FOR category IN (&categories)) p;

DROP TABLE temp;
```

#### Result from either script

```
SQL> @test_tsql_conversion.sql


Table TEMP created.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


       CATEGORY_LIST
____________________
'ABC','DEF','GHI'


old:SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT date_val, amount, category FROM temp) x
       PIVOT (MAX (amount) FOR category IN (&categories)) p
new:SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT date_val, amount, category FROM temp) x
       PIVOT (MAX (amount) FOR category IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI')) p

    DATE_VAL    'ABC'    'DEF'    'GHI'
____________ ________ ________ ________
01-FEB-12                  500      800
10-FEB-12                  700
01-JAN-12        1000
01-MAR-12        1100


Table TEMP dropped.
```

Comment: If we were to use the values dynamically instead of hardcoding 
column values , should we create a procedure ?

Comment: Because the final select is doing a `SELECT *` if there are any additional categories, they will appear in the column list. You can test it by adding an additional insert statement with another category.

Comment: No I meant like dynamically adding new columns from the category variable without hardcoding the values

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If additional categories exist, they will be dynamically added as columns in the result because `SELECT *` is used. There is nowhere in the scripts (other than the insert statements) that the categories are hard coded. The number of columns will depend on the number of categories that exist in the data set.

Comment: When I tried to run the earlier than version query it says distinct option not allowed for this function and bind variable not supported inside pivot unpivot operation. Query on result script worked fine

Comment: The last block is not a script. It is the output from running either the first or second script from SQLPlus or SQLcl

Comment: Ok so if it's that way I'm getting the above said error

Comment: `SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT date_val, amount, category FROM temp) x
       PIVOT (MAX (amount) FOR category IN (&categories)) p;` Shouldnt this be `category _list`

Comment: Do you happen to know how to resolve Ok this error  `: [Code: 1489, SQL State: 72000]  ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
ORA-06512: at "pivot_categories", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

Building on EJ Egyed's answer, here is a PL/SQL version:

```
declare
    cols   long;
    query  long;
    results sys_refcursor;
begin
    select '''' || listagg(category||''' as "'||upper(category)||'"', ', ''') within group (order by category)
    into   cols
    from   (select distinct category from temp);

    query :=
    'select * from 
     ( select dt, amount, category
       from temp ) x
     pivot 
     ( max(amount) for category in ('||cols||') ) p';

    open results for query;
    dbms_sql.return_result(results);
end;
```

The solution will vary depending on how you want to execute the code. `dbms_sql.return_result` will pass the result set to a 12c or later client such as  SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, but might not work with third party tools such as DbVisualizer or Tableau. SQL*Plus is Oracle's basic command line tool used mostly for administration and deployment scripts, but not really suited for end user reporting. SQL Developer is a programmer's IDE, which a business analyst might use, but again it's not really for general end users.

The most generic approach might be to write this as a procedure that returns a refcursor, which could then be processed by an application written in Java, C# etc.

A procedure version would look like this:

```
create or replace procedure pivot_categories
    ( out_results out sys_refcursor )
as
    cols   long;
    query  long;
begin
    select '''' || listagg(category||''' as "'||upper(category)||'"', ', ''') within group (order by category)
    into   cols
    from   (select distinct category from temp);

    query :=
    'select * from 
     ( select dt, amount, category
       from temp ) x
     pivot 
     ( max(amount) for category in ('||cols||') ) p';

    open out_results for query;
end pivot_categories;
```

Comment: Im facin difficulty to run it in DB-viz. The code looks fine. I wrote it as a function.After the function definition next line `DECLARE` is throwing a error.Also `long` is used for numbers or can be used inplace of `varchar2` also?

Comment: Also `within group (order by category)
    into   cols` part is thrwing an error saying  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "GROUP" when expecting one of the following:, from into bulk

Comment: A function probably shouldn't have any `declare` keyword in it. What does it return and how are you calling it? PL/SQL's [`long`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-89ABA12C-6096-446C-9E2C-65687A0B8DA9) is a short way of writing `VARCHAR2(32760)` and has nothing to do with numbers. It's supposed to be deprecated because it's associated with the old, obsolete `long` column type which they had before `clob` came along, but really it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your Procedure, it compiled successfully. Now through the command editor how do I call it? `@call pivot_categories` or `EXEC : ` ?

Comment: I've never used DBVisualiser, so no idea I'm afraid. `call` is a valid SQL keyword. `@` and `exec` are not, but they are part of SQL\*Plus (`@` calls a script, not a procedure, and `exec blahblah` is a shortcut for `begin blahblah; end;`) so might be carried over into DBVis, or they might not. I see `@call` used in the [DB Visualizer User Guide](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Executing+a+Code+Object) so maybe you'll need to start there.

Comment: `@call` usually works but im new to work with `sys_refcursor` type variable.  so logically how its supposed to be called as its not an in parameter rather than a out parameter.`@call  pivot_categories()` doesnt work,

Comment: You have to provide a cursor variable that it can open with the result, e.g. `@call pivot_categories(yourCursorHere)`, where `yourCursorHere` is a ref cursor. I don't know how you do that in DBVis.

Comment: I tried `VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := pivot_categories_RS;
PRINT rc` this too in the SQL commander window to excecute the proc, it doesnt work, how does one do it in `SQL-Developer` ?

Comment: Ok I  figured out that we have an inbuilt execte button which will execute , but the problem im facing is this `: [Code: 1489, SQL State: 72000]  ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
ORA-06512: at "pivot_categories", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Comment: `listagg` can't return more than 4000 bytes. You could lose spaces and `as` keywords or even the whole alias to make the generated line shorter, but there will always be a limitation if you have a lot of categories. An alternative might be to build the list dynamically in a PL/SQL loop instead of using `listagg`.

Comment: But then i used `long` wont that help.. I want to make double sure that its showing the correct error. I tried my same code on `db fiddle` and it works, but on db viz it shows the above said error

Comment: I have max 5 categories, each word is max 15-16 letters(underscore included)

Comment: Apologies, there was an error in my code - try now. I couldn't reproduce the error though so I can't be sure that fixed it. `listagg()` can't construct a list of more than 4000 bytes regardless of what variable you put that list into.

Comment: Ys when you run it as a procedure and you have lot of data it gives an error, do you know how to resolve it with `xmlagg` ? I am not sure what you have updated in the code though.. I have raised asked s new question, about the error of you know someone who could answer it please do share : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197582/error-in-concatenation-of-listagg-function

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need:

```
create table temp
(
    date timestamp(3),
    category varchar2(3),
    amount number
);

insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)


 v_cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
    v_query  NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' || QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR INTO v_cols FROM dual XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

v_query := 'SELECT date, ' || v_cols || ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' || v_cols || ')
            ) p '


execute immediate v_query

drop table temp
```

also there is an online sql convert tool : http://www.sqlines.com/online

Comment: No this didn't I tried converting and tried to run it.I am using DB viz pro version. I'm not sure of it's a DBVIZ error or there is error in the code it doesn't run. I'm using SQL commander of DBVIz to run the code

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a `stuff()` function or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `FOR INTO` can't be right, and `from dual xml path(''),type)` doesn't seem to make any sense.